# AngularJS, filter on checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a `ul` with `ng-repeat`, and I am trying to make some values hide when a checkbox is unticked. Essentially I have 2 different statuses in a JSON file: `new` and `completed`.

I want completed ones to show when a checkbox is ticked and for them to hide when a checkbox is unticked.

My code is below:

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="$ctrl.query" placeholder="Search">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="self.information">
  <span> Show Completed </span>
</div>
<div class="container:fluid" id="list">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="info in self.information | 
         filter: {'status': 'complete'}" ng-show="self.information">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- LI CONTENTS -->
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Making a jsfiddle always makes it easier for others to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="$ctrl.query" placeholder="Search">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="self.information" ng-true-value="completed" ng-false-value="new">
  <span> Show Completed </span>
</div>
<div class="container:fluid" id="list">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="info in self.information | 
         filter: {'status': self.information}">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- LI CONTENTS -->
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Tahnks a lot, but sorry it didn't work, I'm going to add a fiddle now to help!